# how to create blob container inside Storage Account using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I am working to create Azure Storage Account with Container using ARM templates. I have followed azure [quick-start templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-storage-blob-container/azuredeploy.json) for reference.

I have used the following lines of code for creating Storage Account with Container.

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "kind": "StorageV2",
  "properties": {
    "accessTier": "Hot"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('containerName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

After deployment, I can see only the Storage Account but not the Container inside it.

So, can anyone suggest me how to create Container inside Storage Account using ARM templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deployed the ARM template, there should have been an error.
[image]

The error is because your ARM template is missing a segment of the name for the container. You'll need to include the following segment.
[image]

Comment: I want to give custom container name instead of doing `concat`

Comment: Using `concat` is necessary when working with child resources in order build a valid name for the resource. The concatenated 'default/' segment does not appear when accessing the container.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-invalid-template#solution-2---incorrect-segment-lengths